# how can I do Map placement in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to do Map placement in hadoop. It means that I want to choose that which part of data be processed on which machine? how can I make it? Thanks

Comment: have you looked at [FairScheduler](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html#Automatically_placing_applications_in_queues)? you can create small apps for each data type and create queues to process these apps by FairScheduler. Also look into [hazelcast](https://hazelcast.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using node labels:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeLabel.html

Comment: Thanks, But I think this cannot help me because I want to do map placement. it means that I want that for example first 64 MB be prmbocessed on machine 1, second 64MB be processed on machine 3 and third 64 MB be proceseed on machine 2.